# D3D11 Map call is slow even after fence signaled

Tags: c, windows, shader, directx-11

Im running a compute shader. It takes about .22ms to complete (according to D3D11 Query), but real world time is around .6ms on average. The map call definitely takes up some time! It computes a dirty [RECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd162897(v=vs.85)) that contains all the pixels that have changed since the last frame and returns it back to the CPU. This all works great!

My issue is that the map call is very slow. Normal performance is optimal, at around .6ms, but if I run this is the background with any GPU intensive application (blender, AAA game, etc) it really starts to slow down, I see times jump the normal .6ms all the way to 9ms! I need to figure out why the map is taking so long!

The shader is passing the result into this structure here

```
buffer_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(RECT);
buffer_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(RECT);
buffer_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
buffer_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
buffer_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
buffer_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
hr = ID3D11Device5_CreateBuffer(ctx->device, &buffer_desc, NULL, &ctx->reduction_final);
```

With a UAV of

```
uav_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
uav_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
uav_desc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
uav_desc.Buffer.NumElements = 1;
uav_desc.Buffer.Flags = 0;
hr = ID3D11Device5_CreateUnorderedAccessView(ctx->device, (ID3D11Resource*) ctx->reduction_final, &uav_desc, &ctx->reduction_final_UAV);
```

Copying it into this staging buffer here

```
buffer_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(RECT);
buffer_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(RECT); 
buffer_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
buffer_desc.BindFlags = 0;
buffer_desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
buffer_desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
hr = ID3D11Device5_CreateBuffer(ctx->device, &buffer_desc, NULL, &ctx->cpu_staging);
```

and mapping it like so

```
hr = ID3D11DeviceContext4_Map(ctx->device_ctx, (ID3D11Resource*) ctx->cpu_staging, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mapped_res);
```

I added a fence to my system so I could timeout if it took too long (if it took longer than 1ms).

Creation of fence and event

```
hr = ID3D11Device5_CreateFence(ctx->device, 1, D3D11_FENCE_FLAG_NONE, &IID_ID3D11Fence, (void**) &ctx->fence);
ctx->fence_handle = CreateEventA(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
```

Then after my dispatch calls I copy into the staging, then signal the fence

```
ID3D11DeviceContext4_CopyResource(ctx->device_ctx, (ID3D11Resource*) ctx->cpu_staging, (ID3D11Resource*) ctx->reduction_final);
ID3D11DeviceContext4_Signal(ctx->device_ctx, ctx->fence, ++ctx->fence_counter);
hr = ID3D11Fence_SetEventOnCompletion(ctx->fence, ctx->fence_counter, ctx->fence_handle);
```

This all seems to be working. The fence signals and allows WaitForSingleObject to pass, and when I wait on it, I can timeout here and move on to other things while this finishes, then come back (this is not OK obviously, I want the data from the shader ASAP).

```
DWORD waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(ctx->fence_handle, 1);
if (waitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    LOG("Timeout Count: %u", ++timeout_count);
    return false;
}
else
{
    LOG("Timeout Count: %u", timeout_count);

    ID3D11DeviceContext4_Map(ctx->device_ctx, (ID3D11Resource*) ctx->cpu_staging, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mapped_res);
    memcpy(rect, mapped_res.pData, sizeof(RECT));
    ID3D11DeviceContext4_Unmap(ctx->device_ctx, (ID3D11Resource*) ctx->cpu_staging, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Problem is, the map can still take a long time (ranging from .6 to 9ms). The fence signals once everything is done right? Which takes less than 1ms. But the map call itself can take a long time still. What gives? What am I missing about how mapping works? Is it possible to reduce the time to map? Is the fence signaling before the copy happens?

So just to re-cap. My shader runs fast under normal operations. around .6ms total time, with .22ms time for the shader itself (and Im assuming the rest is the mapping). Once I start running my shader while rendering with blender, it starts to seriously slow down. The fence tells me that the work is still being complete in record time, but the map call still is taking a very long time (upwards of 9ms).

Other random things i've tried:

Setting SetGPUThreadPriority to 7.

Setting AvSetMmThreadCharacteristicsW to "DisplayPostProcessing", "Games", and "Capture"

Setting AvSetMmThreadPriority to AVRT_PRIORITY_CRITICAL

Comment: Not sure of what you're doing overall but copying (with synchronization) between CPU and GPU is always "slow". Why do you need to do that at each frame (if I understand correctly)? You should have everything on the GPU for max performance.

Comment: @SimonMourier, I wish I could leave the resulting RECT on the GPU, but sadly it has to head to the CPU for another API call. I didnt expect copying over 16bytes from GPU to CPU to take 9ms at times. I might try this whole thing in CUDA and see if i can see some different results? There has to be something I am missing.